# Changing the name of a file based on a part of its original name that are between the first two instances of a character

Tags: linux, bash, grep, regular-expression, rename

I am trying to change the names of my files based on the string between the first two instances of "|". This is what my problem looks like:

>1234|**interest1**|randomstuff1.txt

>5678|**interest2**|randomstuff2.txt

>9101112|**interest3**|randomstuff3|trickything.txt

And my desired output is:

**interest1.txt**

**interest2.txt**

**interest3.txt**

I've tried some stuff using regex and variables in bash but I wasn't able to achieve the results that I wanted.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you showing us the file names or the file contents? Do you really have file _names_ starting with `>`? Could these be fasta sequence files perhaps and you want to rename based on the information in the header?

Comment: Also, what operating system are you using? You said Linux, but which one? do you have `rename` and, if you do, do you know which one? If you tell us your distribution we should be able to make a good guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script assumes that you want to process all files that contain at least two `|` characters and end with `.txt`. The example file names in the question would also match `*interest*.txt`. If your requirement is different, please, clarify this in the question.

If the output is what you expect, remove the `echo` before `mv` to actually rename the files. The comments `# ...` are only to explain the code and can be omitted.

```
for f in *\|*\|*.txt
do
    n="${f#*|}"  # remove leading shortest string matching *|
    n="${n%%|*}" # remove trailing longest string matching |*
    echo mv "$f" "$n".txt
done
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Using the Perl-based `rename` utility, rename all files whose names match the pattern `*interest*.txt`.  Each file is renamed by splitting the original name on the pipe symbols and then using the second resulting field with `.txt` added to the end:

```bash
rename -n -v '$_ = (split /\|/)[1] . ".txt"' *interest*.txt
```

Remove the `-n` option when you have made sure that the command outputs the correct new names.

Testing on the names given in the question:

```bash
$ ls -1
>1234|interest1|randomstuff1.txt
>5678|interest2|randomstuff2.txt
>9101112|interest3|randomstuff3|trickything.txt
```

```bash
$ rename -v '$_ = (split /\|/)[1] . ".txt"' *interest*.txt
>1234|interest1|randomstuff1.txt renamed as interest1.txt
>5678|interest2|randomstuff2.txt renamed as interest2.txt
>9101112|interest3|randomstuff3|trickything.txt renamed as interest3.txt
```

```bash
$ ls -1
interest1.txt
interest2.txt
interest3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I've assumed that we're interested in files starting with `>`, containing (at least) two of your delimiter symbols (`|`) and ending with `.txt`:

Example

```
# Preparation
touch '>1234|interest1|randomstuff1.txt' '>5678|interest2|randomstuff2.txt' '>9101112|interest3|randomstuff3|trickything.txt'

# Process
for f in '>'*'|'*'|'*.txt
do
    x="${f#*|}"                      # Remove from start until first found '|'
    x="${x%%|*}.txt"                 # Remove from first found `|` to end

    printf "%s -> %s\n" "$f" "$x"    # Show what would happen
    # mv -f "$f" "$x"                # Do it (if uncommented)
done
```

Output (without `mv`)

```
>1234|interest1|randomstuff1.txt -> interest1.txt
>5678|interest2|randomstuff2.txt -> interest2.txt
>9101112|interest3|randomstuff3|trickything.txt -> interest3.txt
```

Uncomment the `mv` command to move the files. Note that if you have duplicate target names the last one processed will be the one that remains.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl-rename` (called `rename` on many systems), you can do:

```
$ rename -n 's/.*?\|(.+?)\|.*/$1.txt/' *txt 
>1234|interest1|randomstuff1.txt -> interest1.txt
>5678|interest2|randomstuff2.txt -> interest2.txt
>9101112|interest3|randomstuff3|trickything.txt -> interest3.txt
```

If the output looks like what you want, run the command again without the `-n` to actually rename the files.